# MySql Script to search all non ascii and reaplace with space

Tags: mysql

Can I ask for some sort of script to search for an ascii ranging from DLE way up to US. You can check it at [ASCII TABLE](http://www.asciitable.com).

I have a code which suppposedly search for a non ascii character but I also want to replace it with a space at the same time.

Here's my code

```
SELECT *
from
`TABLE_NAME`(Sample only)
where COLUMN_NAME(sample only)
like %non-keyboard character(sample only(1st non keyboard character))% or
like %non-keyboard character(sample only(2nd non keyboard character))%.....
```

The code above is long since I used it from DLE down to US.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See this site http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/14/bad-character-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search range from DLE to US using [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html). With REGEXP you can specify non-ascii character like [.DLE.].

```
SELECT col
FROM tab
WHERE col REGEXP '[[.DLE.]-[.US.]]';
```

But, Unforfunately there is no way to replace using REGEXP something like `REG_STR_REPLACE()`. please refere to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

So you should call `REPLACE()` several times but this is slow. You have three choices.

**1**.

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(col, CHAR(16), ''), CHAR(17), ''), CHAR(18), '')
FROM ...
```

**2**. install udf explained in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

**3**. do in client side

Comment: So Number 1 will actually show if a cell in a column within the table has non keybaord characters? Am I right?

Comment: And is this correct I used it but never returned an error `UPDATE table SET column = raplce(column, char(16-31), '')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
update tablename
set columnToCheck = replace(columnToCheck , char(146), '');
```

or

```
UPDATE tablename
SET columnToCheck = REPLACE(CONVERT(columnToCheck USING ascii), '?', '')
WHERE ...
```

Font: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/14/bad-character-data-in-mysql/